# HsqlDB not specify the column or table in the error message

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm using HsqlDB 2.2.8 for some time and I can't figure out some way to the log shows what column or table have some problem. I tried to upgrade to 2.3.4 (last version), but the behavior is the same.

For example, using Hibernate, I'm trying to find the origin of a query error from Hsqldb when the Hibernate do a `find`. In Hibernate we have:

```
em.find(SomeEntity.class, id);
```

Looking the stacktrace, the error from Hibernate side is:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
```

The error from HsqlDB side:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
```

This is not an isolated case. Many errors from HsqlDB not show the table and column, like this:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: string data, right truncation
```

Or calling a procedure:

```
incompatible data type in conversion / Error Code: -5561 / State: 42561
```

I'm was looking for some way to log more information from HsqlDB. I try this when I was debugging:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("hsqldb.db").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG)
```

But not work.

So, how to discover what table and column has this `invalid character`?

Comment: Turn on SQL logging on HSQLDB actual SQL and parameters to help you find out what is wrong.

Comment: @fredt the query is very big: more than 100 columns and more than 15 tables. Sadly, is impracticable discover the problem only looking the SQL. I have a similar problem weeks ago in a single `INSERT` in a single table and I  spend a lot of time to discover what is wrong.